# QTableView adding items crash

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, qtableview

I am new to Qt. My program is crashing when adding items read from XML to QTableView.

XML file:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Accounts>
    <Host>host1</Host>
    <Login>dawid1</Login>
    <Password>pass1</Password>
    <Status>status1</Status>
    <Host>host2</Host>
    <Login>dawid2</Login>
    <Password>pass2</Password>
    <Status>status2</Status>
</Accounts>

Adding items code:

```
QXmlStreamReader xmlReader;
QAbstractItemModel *model = ui->tableView->model();

xmlReader.setDevice(&file);

while(!xmlReader.atEnd())
{
    QXmlStreamReader::TokenType token = xmlReader.readNext();

    if(token == QXmlStreamReader::StartDocument)
    {
        continue;
    }

    if(token == QXmlStreamReader::StartElement)
    {
        if(xmlReader.name() == "Accounts")
            continue;

        if(xmlReader.name() == "Host")
        {
            model->insertRow(model->rowCount());
            model->setData(model->index(model->rowCount(),0), xmlReader.readElementText()); //probably here crash
        }
        if(xmlReader.name() == "Login")
        {
            model->insertRow(model->rowCount());
            model->setData(model->index(model->rowCount(),1), xmlReader.readElementText());
        }
        if(xmlReader.name() == "Password")
        {
            model->insertRow(model->rowCount());
            model->setData(model->index(model->rowCount(),2), xmlReader.readElementText());
        }
        if(xmlReader.name() == "Status")
        {
            model->insertRow(model->rowCount());
            model->setData(model->index(model->rowCount(),3), xmlReader.readElementText());
        }
    }

    if(xmlReader.hasError())
    {
            QMessageBox::critical(this, "XML Parse Error",xmlReader.errorString(), QMessageBox::Ok);
    }
}
xmlReader.clear();
file.close();
```

My questions are:

**1. Why program is crashing and how to fix it?**

**2. For future: How to localize crash reason and fix it in QtCreator?**

Regards, David

Comment: Crashing?, no error to speak of?

Comment: Windows 7 Message: "program has stopped working"

Comment: If you run with the debugger as per my answer, please update your question, so we can further help you.

Answer (score 3):

As for your issue number "2" : you can run your code with debugger in **QtCreator** : it's the second play-like button, with a little bug on it. This way, when your application crashes you will know where.

The line that caused the crash will be pointed at by an arrow next to the line numbers, and you will have stack trace available and variable value lookup.

Also if you suspect which part of code causes a crash (or other unexpected behaviour) you can place a breakpoint right before it. Click on a line number and a small red ball should appear. Then run with debugger, and your application will stop at the breakpoint, so you can review your variable values, and then trace the execution step by step.